# Is there any difference between using typeset in ksh to simply setting a variable?

Tags: shell, ksh

Are the following 2 lines completely equivalent?  If not what's the difference?  I've seen plenty of shell scripts utilize number 1 and was just wondering what it gives you compared with number 2.

1. `typeset TARGET="${XMS_HOME}/common/jxb/config/${RUNGROUP}.${ENV}.properties"`
2. `TARGET="${XMS_HOME}/common/jxb/config/${RUNGROUP}.${ENV}.properties"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeset` will create a local variable (one which doesn't "leak"). This is useful in functions but I've also seen it being used at the top level of a shell script.

```
a=0
function x {
    typeset a=1
}
x
echo $a
function y {
    a=2
}
y
echo $a
```

will print

```
0
2
```

You can also use `typeset` to create arrays and integers.

**[EDIT]** Added `function` keyword because some shells require it. Remove it if it offends your shell but it should work with most versions.

Comment: Your sample code works as expected with bash and the legacy ksh (ksh88) but not with ksh93 which requires the functions to be declared with the `function name {` syntax, not the `name() {` one.

Comment: It should work with all of them outside perhaps on antique releases.

Comment: With the function keyword, you shouldn't use parenthesis. While bash accepts this redundant syntax, it is an error with ksh.

Answer (score 0):

since shell scripting is a loosely typed language (in which variables wont have a datytype) we can use typeset to set a particular variable to take similar datatype of values only.